# Https site not open localy

Tags: php, ssl, https, localhost, wamp

I uplode my site in host with ssl certificate and the links alredy becom https but after that I when i run my project in localhost it is directed me to online so, is there any configration in wamp server need to change ? How Can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove code from .htaccess or .webconfig file of localhost project folder.